# How to scale UIVIew to fit in a4 Paper size

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiview

I am developing application to convert `UIView` to PDF file and fit it into A4 paper size to print.

How can I scale any `UIView` to fit into A4 paper size?

I ned my `UIView` to completely fit into an A4 page.

Comment: Add your view in a scrollview with fix A4 Paper size frame.

Comment: Use UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile to convert to PDF and print. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11809133/742298

Comment: i wan to scale UIVIew to A4 Paper size

Comment: If your UIView has size 1024x768, and your PDF page has size 792x612, then to make sure that all of the UIView is visible in the PDF output, you must scale the context appropriately. 792 / 1023 = 0.733, which is the scaling factor:

CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 0.773f, 0.773f); 
-- as suggested by the link in @Lion's answer

Answer (score 2):

you can convert something like,

```
    func createPdfFromView(aView: UIView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String)
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    aView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first {
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
        debugPrint(documentsFileName)
        pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

Read [this article](https://concentricsky.com/blog/article/creating-multipage-pdf-document-uiviews-ios) for more details and to know that how to render it in different sizes.

Comment: This is perfect but this will not scale UIVIew to fit in A4 Paper size